# Responsive width for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css

This is my first time building a responsive site, and as I tailor the CSS for the iPhone I'm running into a problem.  The styles all apply correctly, the text changes size and the wrapper changes widths. The problem is the iPhone browser still opens up at a huge width, see the screenshot:

[image]

I'm using

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

to set the specific iPhone css. `body {width:;}` doesn't work.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the following to your page header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
```

As in:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
	<head>
		<title></title>
		<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
	</head>
	<body>
	</body>
</html>
```